# yii2 redirect in controller action does not work?

Tags: redirect, yii2

I am posting a form to /user/save in order to save user data. The problem occurs when i try to redirect the user if the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is NOT 'post'.

My user controller code

```
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\MyUser;

class UserController extends Controller {

public function actionSave() {

    if(!Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()) {
       $this->redirect('/user/index',302);
       exit(0);
   }

   //do something to save user submitted data       
}

}//~CLASS
```

The is no way to get the redirection to work. Although `!Yii::$app->request->getIsPost() is false` the call to `$this->redirect does nothing!`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Yii2 we need to `return()` the result from the action.I think you need to add a `return` in front of your redirect.

```
  return $this->redirect(['user/index']);
```

Comment: Return to function is not necessary for redirect. If you use exit after redirect then it will not work. What is happening don't know

Comment: Below there is one answer if you are using inside before action..." If you are trying to do redirect in beforeAction() you should use send() method"

`return $this->redirect('/some/url',302)->send();`

Answer (score 34):

If you are trying to do redirect in **beforeAction()** you should use **send()** method

```
 return $this->redirect('/some/url',302)->send();
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 12):

You can redirect by this method also:

```
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['user/index', 'id' => 10]);
```

If you want to send the Header information immediately use with **send()**.This method adds a **Location** header to the current response.

```
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['user/index', 'id' => 10])->send();
```

If you want the complete URL then use like `Url::to(['user/index', 'id' => 302])` with the header of `use yii\helpers\Url;`.

For more information check [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#redirect%28%29-detail).
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with redirect not working for very long,
none of what mentioned above was working for me, until I tried this:

Change:

```
return $this->redirect('site/secure');
```

to:

```
return $this->redirect(['site/secure']);
```

In other words, needed to enclose it within [] brackets!
I am using PHP 7, might be the reason why?

Comment: enclosing within `[]` brackets is yii2 standard.

Comment: Yes, and that's what array() does, I see now!

Comment: Still, I am confused why not even my latest Yii2 tutorial is using neither ['text'] or array('text') on the redirect('text') command.

Comment: Thank you, it was my problem

Answer (score 5):

Redirects the browser to the specified URL.

This method adds a "Location" header to the current response. Note that it does not send out the header until send() is called. In a controller action you may use this method as follows:

```
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url);
```

In other places, if you want to send out the "Location" header immediately, you should use the following code:

```
Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url)->send();
return;
```

Comment: FYI, refer this link :  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#redirect()-detail

Answer (score 3):

here is another way to do this

```
if(!Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()) {
    return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array('/user/index',302));
}
```

Comment: thanks but please use  url::to() class to give better url..best regards

Answer (score 2):

**try by this**

```
if(!Yii::$app->request->getIsPost()) 
{
  Yii::$app->response->redirect(array('user/index','id'=>302));
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be referring to YII v.1.X code. Is this Yii v.1.X code?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `exit(0);` That's bad practice at the best of times. Use `Yii::$app->end();`

So your code would look like

```
$this->redirect(['index'], 302);
Yii::$app->end();
```

That said though the actual problem was stopping POST requests, this is the wrong solution to that problem (although it does work). To stop POST requests you need to use [access control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html).

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['create', 'update'],
            'rules' => [
                // deny all POST requests
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'verbs' => ['POST']
                ],
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use beforeAction then try this :

```
public function beforeAction($act){
  if($act->actionMethod=="actionSomeaction"){
     if(!$somecondition){
        $act->actionMethod="actionIndex"; //this will redirect to index page
     }
  }
  return parent::beforeAction($act);
}
```